# VSCODE Jump to the JS file definition (not the .d.ts file)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm sure thousands of other JS devs are feeling the pain I'm feeling. I love jumping to  function definitions in `.d.ts` files while browsing code in VS Code.

However, sometimes instead of going to the `.d.ts` file, I'd like to jump to the raw JS code that is being hidden by the .d.ts file that sits in front of it.

Does anyone know how to optionally force a jump to the JS source code (if it exists) and not a TypeScript definition file.

Thanks!

EDIT: I am aware that this has been asked for to the VS Code team and will not be officially supported by them. I'm looking for some sort of hacky workaround (extension or otherwise) to get this to work.

Comment: The "jump-to" behavior that you're describing is for navigating to a type definition. If you write TypeScript source code, then it also happens to jump to your implementation, but otherwise, that's just incidental.

Comment: @jsejcksn if I write plain JS code, vscode will jump me to that code. But, if I stick a .d.ts file in front of the JS, then I can ONLY jump to that file, not the JS code anymore. I'd like to be able to do both

Comment: There are various similar-but-different behaviors for code navigation in VS Code. Do [one of these](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition) answer your question?

Comment: @jsejcksn thanks for the tip but unfortunately I tried all of different options and am unable to jump anywhere other than the .d.ts file.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68782). This feature is not supported. A few comments in the issue that I referenced explain why.

Comment: @ztcollazo I understand that it is not supported. I want a dirty workaround because this functionality would be VERY helpful to me.

Comment: I would look around the source code of the file. If you can find the file path of the .d.ts file, you may be able to figure out the file path of the .js file. Example: client.d.ts -> client.js. If this doesn't work, I would poke around elsewhere (package.json exports, etc).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Recently [announced](https://twitter.com/mattbierner/status/1517182624917340162), VS Code Insiders (v1.67.2) supports a `Go to Source Definition` context menu option from right-clicking the symbol. This was [committed 19-APR-2022](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/d851ea5d49b0ec89b98765d9e0084c25f2ff5031).

This feature requires [TypeScript 4.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/?q=1#go-to-source-definition):

> ### Go To Source Definition
>
> TypeScript 4.7 contains support for a new experimental editor command called *Go To Source Definition*. It’s similar to *Go To Definition*, but it never returns results inside declaration files. Instead, it tries to find corresponding implementation files (like `.js` or `.ts` files), and find definitions there — even if those files are normally shadowed by `.d.ts` files.
>
> This comes in handy most often when you need to peek at the implementation of a function you’re importing from a library instead of its type declaration in a `.d.ts` file.
>
> [image: go to source definition screencast]
>
> You can try this new command in the latest versions of Visual Studio Code. Note, though, that this functionality is still in preview, and there are some known limitations. In some cases TypeScript uses heuristics to guess which `.js` file corresponds to the given result of a definition, so these results might be inaccurate. Visual Studio Code also doesn’t yet indicate whether a result was a guess, but it’s something we’re collaborating on.
>
> You can leave feedback about the feature, read about known limitations, or learn more at [our dedicated feedback issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49003).

Comment: unfortunately this takes me to the dist/index.js file (instead of the dist/index.d.ts for the standard "go to type definition" shortcut. What I want is to go to src/index.ts !

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the new "Go to Source Definition" command/context menu item [mentioned by tony19](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72333657/6911703), VSCode now has options for "Prefer Go To Source Definition" which allow you to still use the "Go to Definition" command, and will fall back to showing the type definition if the source definition is not available.

[image: "Prefer Go To Source Definition" options in VSCode settings]

Answer (score -6):

### Delete the `.d.ts` file (temporarily)

This is obviously a super-crappy workaround, but it should work. By deleting the file you don't want to see, VSC will only have one place to take you: the file you *do* want to see.

1. When VSC takes you to the `.d.ts` file, right-click on the file tab and click "Copy Relative Path"
2. Open the VSC terminal and enter `rm [PATH]` (or `del [PATH]` for Windows)

   - leave the (now-deleted) `.d.ts` file tab open
3. Go back to the original file and try navigation again

   - if it doesn't work, you may need to reboot the TS server
4. Once you've seen the code you want to see, go back to the `.d.ts` file and save it

   - this will put the file back exactly as it was, which will probably be invisible to your source-control
   - if not, you may need to use your SCM to undo the deletion operation

Again, an awful hack. And I share your frustration that the VSC maintainers & community have no interest in this feature. Just bear in mind that their goal is to make their propriety technology displace all technology they don't own, so you will occasionally discover that they will refuse to help you *as a web developer* because they want you to be a *Microsoft developer*.

Comment: Personal attacks and baseless accusations are not appropriate for a technical forum. By all means leave the technical workaround, but post the rest someplace else (e.g. Twitter).

Comment: Looks like you may have just been proven wrong if the fix in the answer above does land.. not sure where the vendetta against vs code is coming from.

Comment: Incidentally, the new VS Code feature does not seem to work. I consider OP's question still unsolved by the vendor.